# Java how to use activity methods in another class

Tags: java, android, android-activity

For example I have an activity class. In this class I have some variables and I'd like to use them in another class. This is the code:

```
public class SearchView {
    private MenuActivity menuActivity;

    public SearchView() {
        menuActivity = new MenuActivity();
        menuActivity.searchButton = (ImageView) menuActivity.findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
    }
}
```

Last line gives me a `NullPointerException`. I know I need to initialize it but how can I initialize an activity?

Comment: what is the null object ? R ?

Comment: Maybe menuActivity.searchButton is not an ImageView? Please check it first

Comment: Why you are creating menuactivity yourself? You have to pass it from some where else and you have to define public methods in your activity to call them

Comment: You should never instantiate a activity class. if you want the view in another actvity you need to have the same in the layout. Also what is `SearchView` and why do you need the same?

Answer (score 2):

You have a different options...

### First one:

Create a getter to get values from classes:

```
public MenuActivity getMenuActivityVar(){
    return this.MenuActivity;
}
```

From other activity using this method like this:

```
//Other activity or class
//Declare a new var as your class
SearchView sView = new SearchView();

MenuActivity nMenu = sView.getMenuActivityVar();
```

### Second one:

In this case is a static method means that all static vars have a static value you don't need declare a new class from this one because is static.

```
public static class SearchView {{
    public static MenuActivity menuActivity;
    .
    .

}
```

With this change you can call this var using:

```
//This call it's do it from other activity
MyNewVar = SearchView.MenuActivity;
```

### Third one:

```
public class SearchView {
    public MenuActivity menuActivity;
}
```

From the other activity when you create a class like this:

```
SearchView sView = new SearchView();
//In this moment your var are null.
```

After if you modify this var in your class from methods for example then you can get var using like this:

```
MenuActivity MyNewMenu = sView.menuActivity;
```

I think the best option is first, it's the best important part of classes getters and setters from classes. Tell me if I helped you and good programming!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SearchView {
    private MenuActivity menuActivity;

    public SearchView(Activity activityRef) {
        MenuActivity.searchButton = (ImageView) activityRef.findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
    }
}
```

And declare searchButton as public static in activity.

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {
    public static Button searchButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        SearchView searchView = new SearchView(this);
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you. let me know once you are done.

Comment: This one works , thank you . I didn't try the others by the way .

Comment: I did , it was '-1' before :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value of the variable 
    pass it to next activity using intents.
    if it is a static value make it in separate constant file and use it with the class name.
    If it is a view make use of the view again in the next activity.